# Function Inside Function Can't Find Variable

Tags: php, oop, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use the curl headerfunction opt from a class. I've tried putting the functions inside the class normally, but curl can't find them that way. So I put them inside the function I need it in. Here's the part of code that's applicable:

```
    $ht = array();
    $t = array();
    function htWrite($stream,$buffer)
    {
        $ht[] = $buffer;
        return strlen($buffer);
    }
    function tWrite($stream,$buffer)
    {
        $t[] = $buffer;
        return strlen($buffer);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'htWrite');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'tWrite');
```

When I put an echo statement in htWrite for the buffer, it echos out just fine. But if I do a print_r statement on $ht later, it says that it's empty. Further investigation says that it's creating its own $ht variable, because if I remove that line, $ht is null according to the function. So what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at how you can specify object methods as [callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback):

```
class Foo {
    public function Bar() {
        // do whatever
    }

    public function Test() {
        $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'Bar'));
    }
}
```